# HXT: reuse "preparsed" data

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I am trying to 'preparse' XML with HXT into [XmlTree] once and then reuse this data several times.

Below is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

parseXML = readDocument [ withValidate no
                        , withRemoveWS yes  -- throw away formating WS
                        ] 

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)


data UiWindow = UiWindow {
    wndName :: String,
    wndNameLib :: String,
    wndChildren :: [UiWindow]
    } deriving (Show)

initUiWindow = UiWindow {
    wndName = "empty",
    wndNameLib = "",
    wndChildren = []
    }


parseDoc docName = runX $ parseXML fileName >>> getWindow
  where
    fileName = docName ++ ".xml"


getWindow = atTag "Window" >>> proc x -> do
    libraryItemName <- getAttrValue "libraryItemName" -< x
    name <- getAttrValue "name" -< x
    children <- arrIO parseDoc -< libraryItemName
    returnA -< initUiWindow { wndName = name, wndNameLib = libraryItemName, wndChildren = children}


documentName = "DOMDocument.xml"        

parseRoot = parseXML documentName

--runX (parseRoot >>> getWindow )
```

If I parse beforehand:

```
λ: x <- runX parseRoot

λ: :t x
x :: [XmlTree]
λ: :t getWindow
getWindow :: IOSLA (XIOState ()) XmlTree UiWindow
```

How do I run something like this:

```
runX $ XYZ(x) >>> getWindow
```

or this:

```
runX $ XYZ(x) >>> getSomethingElse
```

Allowing me to reuse data in 'x'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more about arrows I found this:

```
λ: :t constA
constA :: ArrowList a => c -> a b c
```

Now using `constA` on an element of type `XmlTree` we get an arrow that we can reuse:

```
main = do
  x <- runX parseRoot
  windows <- runX $ constA (head x) >>> getWindow
  doors <- runX $ constA (head x) >>> getDoor
```

I have to use `head x` as `x` will be of type `[XmlTree]` but the second arrow expects `XmlTree`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the same thing in parseDoc that you do in getWindow:

```
runX $ parseXML filename >>> proc myDoc -> do
    window <- getWindow -< myDoc
    something <- getSomethingElse -< myDoc
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I will end up using. But I am still wondering whether there is a way to convert a simple returned value `x` which I get with `x <- runX parseRoot` to arrow `a` for later use: `runX $ a >>> parseSomething`
`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "convert a value to an arrow". An arrow is a morphism from one value to another. A function is another kind of morphism, so its a bit like saying you want to convert your value into a function.  A function to do what?

Comment: That's right! "Convert a value to an arrow" is exactly what I meant, and there is a function `constA` that does this. I guess I didn't pose original question well enough.